# MongoDB and i18n

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to model an internationalized collection in MongoDB using Mongoose ODM. It just needs to store a String (name) in three languages.

How would you model that Schema? Ive thought on something like this:

```
    _id: ObjectID(...),
    name: {
        en: 'Ten',
        es: 'Diez',
        fr: 'Dix'
    }
```

Is there any way of using an enumeration to indicate the language code, instead of hardcoding them into the Mongoose Schema? I would also appreciate any general tips on how to approach the internationalization of a collection in MongoDB.

**UPDATE:**

I will be finally using mongoose-i18n plugin: https://github.com/elrolito/mongoose-i18n

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can this help you.

in model:

```
first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "models.subscriber.required"]
},
```

in your view

```
      {{#each errors }}
      <p class="mb-0 ">{{ translate this}}</p>
      {{/each}}
```

in your local json file:

```
"models": {
    "subscriber": {
        "required": "The first name is required",
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can follow the following schema:

```
_id: ObjectID(...),
    name:[ 
        'Ten',
        'Diez',
        'Dix'
    ]
```

The advantage of using such a schema over the one mentioned by you is querying will be slightly easier,you can access the field in a particular language by referring to position in the array.It is also easier to add newer entires to the array. The only downside is a particular order has to be followed.